# Call a function that is an attribute

Tags: jquery, function

Is it possible to call a method that is an attribute?

I mean, I have this input (this is created dynamically using jQuery as well when retrieving a list of companies using .get() ):

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:onWorksiteChecked(this,'Virtus Västerås AB, STOCKHOLM','1:201334661','5566109426');" value="1:201334661"/>
```

I have a Select All method that will, as the name suggest Select All this and it's performed as

```
$("#ulworksites li input:checkbox").each(function() {
     if ($(this).attr('disabled') == false) {
        $(this).attr('checked', $("#ckbSelectAll").attr('checked'));

        // Fire onWorksiteChecked method here
        // > as suggested by August Lilleaas in his answer
        $(this).click(); // <-- when this executes I still have the input box to be unchecked, the line above is not perform
     }
  });
```

in the onclick attribute I get the javascript that I need to run for each input (to add that into a list and add the company to be imported, but how can I run it?

```
$(this).attr('checked');
```

[image]

how can I execute that function?

as an add-on, this image shows the list

[image]

- if user click in a checkbox, it will execute the call correctly and add this company into "a basket"
- if user selects all (code above) I want to change all inputs:checkbox to checked and perform the call on each one so I will reuse the code to add each element into "the basket"

**Problem**

The click event fires, but when it fires I still have that input box unchecked (witch will not execute the code right)

Comment: Don't put functions directly in DOM attributes, make the association in jQuery ... can't you move it out?

Comment: but I need to pass values in that, and that is why onclick event does.

Comment: You don’t need the `javascript:` inside an attribute that’s already treated as a script expression. In such cases `javascript:` is interpreted as label (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/label).

Comment: I know... it's just the way I always did it :) it's pure way of writing code, nothing else.

Comment: Good point. Why is it an in-line function in the first place? Make it unobtrusive, and your problem is solved. You can pass values by setting attributes on the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it...

I don't need to select all check boxes before firing the click event, as the jQuery method **click()** will literally click the check box and if is not checked it will check and vice versa.

The `SelectAll` method will only need to be:

```
  $("#ulworksites li input:checkbox").each(function() {
     if ($(this).attr('disabled') == false) {
        $(this).click();
     }
  });
```

This will work for both checking and unchecking.

Answer (score 1):

You can't/shouldn't invoke that code directly. You can fire off the click event, though, which will cause the inline `onclick` code to be called.

```
$("#the_thing").click();
```

You *could* probably have managed to execute the code "directly" by converting it to a string and doing evals, but invoking it indirectly with the click event is a lot better imo.

Comment: bottom line I could do: $(this).attr('checked', $("#ckbSelectAll").attr('checked')).click(); ... when the click() executes I still do not have that input box checked ... not even if I put it in a new line as $(this).click();

Comment: It will be checked. But how is that related anyway?

Comment: That is, it will be checked if you checked it successfully. If it isn't checked in your case, it's because you didn't do it right. Double check that `$("#ckbSelectAll").attr('checked')` returns what you think it returns, etc.

Comment: can you be so kind and see this Screencast ( http://tr.im/yey2 ), when that event fires, you can see that the element is not yet checked.

Comment: the same screencast with the click commented: it does check all inputs ( http://tr.im/yez0 )

Comment: Perhaps you're confused by the fact that the `click` event causes the box to be un-checked if it was checked; clicking a checkbox is what causes it to change state. Take a look at this: http://august.lilleaas.net/_demo/stuff/click_event_on_checkboxes.html. I circumvent changing state by returning false. Not sure how you would be able to do that with your in-line scripts, though..

Comment: the only difference that you have is that you specify "checked" and I pass true or false as you can as well to check / uncheck like: $("input").attr("checked", false)

Comment: You're not an easy person to help. As I mentioned, `return false;` is probably the key here - e.g stopping the event from running, causing the checkbox to not be checked when running the click event.

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question:

Remove `javascript:` from the onclick: it's only meant to be for protocol definitions on hrefs.

To indirectly answer your question:

There's nothing in that page that couldn't be executed without sticking Javascript in the attributes of the HTML. Try:

- Looping through all checkboxes;
- For each checkbox, grab the contents with things like: `$(this).text()`; `$(this).val()`; etc.
- Set them to checked with: `$(this).attr('checked', 'checked');`

Comment: I already do this, as $(this).attr('checked', true); I need to execute the click event, but soon as executes that input is not yet checked as the code should do it before, please see August comments as I added 2 screencasts, thank you.